# Not implemented vs is not implemented

Tags: american-english

Which version is correct?

> *something is not implemented*

or:

> *something not implemented*

It describes the situation of missed feature in software

Comment: Error messages often do not use full sentences, but attempt to express an idea as tersely as possible. Omitting the verb-to-be is quite common in such contexts where terseness is valued (titles, headlines, text messages, error messages, etc).

Comment: So, the full form is "smth is not implemented", but "smth not implemented" accepted as a short form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building off @TRomano's comment:
Both the short form or the long form can be used depending on context.
If you are writing software and generating an error message or throwing an exception, the shorter form is acceptable.  The 'to be' verb is usually dropped to keep the messages shorter.

In a more formal situation, such as if you were explaining in an email to a customer that the feature is not implemented, you would use the long form.